# Historic transaction debug_traceTransaction discrepancy

Tags: contract-debugging, json-rpc

I am currently looking at internal transaction in historic transactions, and wonder if I have encountered a bug for a particular tx: 0xd8aaf9c7f3b5e2389e6899914d6421085e6d3b932fd427180dd7cdb67f83e18d

Ether camp vmtrace lists 44 steps, and no CALL among them
https://live.ether.camp/transaction/d8aaf9c7f3b5e2/vmtrace#0

However debug_traceTransaction for that same transaction returns 64 steps, including a CALL a step 52. That CALL does not seem to be reflected in eth_getBalance, so it looks like a bug of debug_traceTransaction, but is there another possibility?

Edit: opened https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/2522

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a bug, should be fixed in devel and next 1.4.2